# Difference between Bani israel and Israeli jews?

Tags: history, bani-israel

My history is pretty weak, I wanted to understand the difference between these two groups; are bani israel same as the jews currently living in Israel(Palestine)? Are they descendants of bani israel? Anyway related to bani israel, other than being jews?

Comment: This seems like a question more suited for history.

Comment: This question could also be a good fit for some ethnolgy site.... But history seems more appropriate here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit for history stack exchange.

Answer (score -2):

Bani Israel are basically Arabs people belonging to region of modern day Palestine, Jordan, Lebonon and Syria. That includes Arab jews and Arab Christians. It no to do with religion but more to do with people of the region.

Comment: This answer would be more beneficial if you could share evidences supporting your claims.

Answer (score -2):

The Arabic word “إِسْرَائِيلَ” is a combination of two-word Isra and El. Isra has root word “ا س ر” and from this root word it means prisoner and El is God so we can translate Israel as Prisoner of God or Prisoned for God.
If we change this word in Arabic it will become “Isra Ul Llah” meaning “Prisoner of Allah”.

We know that Allah SWT in His divine wisdom made his prophet Yusuf PBUH to be prisoned several years in Egypt. So, in my humble opinion the “Israel” in Quran is referred to Prophet Yusuf PBUH and Bani Israel is a reference to children of Yusuf PBUH not children of Yaqoob PBUH.

There are some mind-boggling similarities and connections in the Quran in reference of Prophet Yusuf PBUH and Israel. There is only one Surah in Quran named Surah Yusuf and there is only one Surah by the name Surah Bani Israel. The individual person “Israel” named twice in Quran Surah Al Imran Ayat 93, Surah Maryam Ayat 58 and Prophet Yusuf PBUH name is also occurred twice in the Quran Surah Al Anam Ayat 84 and and Surah Ghafir (Momin) Ayat 34 besides Sura Yusuf and Aal e Yaqub is also appeared twice in glorious Quran Surah Yusuf Ayat 6 and Surah Maryam Ayat 6.
And the most important fact is that Surah Bani Israel has 111 Ayat and Surah Yusuf has 111 Ayat as well. So, Bani Israel means “Children of Yusuf”.

Today when we say “JEWS” or “YAHUD” it is understood as a group of people who are mainly from the progeny of Prophet Yaqub PBUH. But is it true or correct?
Allah SWT has used a few different words to describe people in the Story of Prophet Musa PBUH. Allah SWT used QOM E MUSA, ASBAAT, AAL E YAQUB, BANI ISRAEL and CHOSEN PEOPLE for these people. Do you think they all are the same and we can easily translate them as “JEWS” or “YAHUD”?
I have a detailed essay where I can prove from the glorious Quran that Allah SWT divided QOM E MUSA into 12 tribes (ASBAT) not Bani Israel. And AAl E YAQUB, BANI ISRAEL and CHOSEN PEOPLE are referred to as the Progeny of Prophet YUSUF PBUH which was one tribe among 12.

If you read the story of Prophet Musa PBUH which is in great detail in the Quran you won’t find the word YAHUD even a single time in this story. What does it mean? It means YAHUD were not part of that struggle and journey and they mixed up later with Bani Israel and other tribes.

I can prove from the Quran that YAHUD are progeny of Qom E Hud and they mixed up with Bani Israel when Talut was appointed as a king. Talut and his followers belonged to YAHUD meaning Qom e Hud. You will find all references of Yahud in the Quran after the timeline of Prophet Dawood PBUH and Prophet Sulaiman PBUH.

We know that Khazars or “ASHKANZI” converted to Judaism after almost 2 centuries of Prophet Muhammad PBUH and after revelation of Quran. So how can we say Yahud of Quran apply on Ashkanazi jews as well? We know they have nothing to do with Qom e Musa, Bani Israel or Yahud. They are progeny of Gog and Magog.

So today when we say “JEWS” it means a group of people who are comprises of or mix of mainly from the progeny of 11 sons of prophet Yaqub PBUH and Prophet Yusuf, Progeny of Qom e Hud and progeny of Gog and Magog and few others who converted to Judaism and they claim that they follow Prophet Musa PBUH.
Today JEWS population in the world is around 15 million and I believe that the majority of them are from the progeny of Aad and from the progeny of Khazars, Gog and Magog. A very minor percentage among them belong to the progeny of 11 sons of prophet Yaqub PBUH and Prophet Yusuf PBUH.

They are classified as ASHKANZIE JEWS, SEPHARDIC JEWS, MIZRAHI JEWS and EITHOHOPIAN JEWS. They can further be divided according to the country they belong to and sect the following.

For a more detailed researched essay please contact

quranfehmi786@gmail.com

Answer (score -2):

Banu or Bani are Derivatives of the word son. Israel is a complete name similar to israfeel. Israfeel is the name of the angel who will blow the horn of judgement day while israel is a name that was given to Jacob, the messenger of Allah according to the ibrahkmic text. Also according to the Jews and Christians, the name can mean the fighter of Allah. The sons of Israel dinesty comes from yahuza, the eldest son of Jacob who was accused to be the leader or putting yuasuf in the depth of the well. The dinestu of Israel and yahuza in turn were mentioned in the quran multiple times and the isareli jews believe that they are the chosen ones who were given multiple chances and failed and punished by Allah. The punishment is widely known amongst the rabi Jews. There is no difference between bani Israel and the state of Israel.